# Duplicate Manifest causes 'Unable to Create Process'

Tags: delphi, manifest

I've been trying a get an update App working with UAC and after doing some digging I needed to include a manifest in my app.

The manifest is called `MyApp.manifest`. In order to include this in the project I've created an RC file which is called `MyApp.rc`. This is built into a file called `MyApp.rec` with a Pre-Build Command `brcc32 $(PROJECTNAME).rc -fo$(PROJECTNAME).rec`

Then in my DPR I Have

```
{$R *.REC}
{$R *.RES}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
```

This allows Delphi to handle things like version information.

This all works fine when the App is copied into windows 7.

I went to debug the app today and my dev environment is Windows XP where I immediately get:
[image: Unable to Create Process]

After some more digging I was pointed to the [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm). Which immediately showed the following problem:

[image: Duplicate Manifest]

The first of these Manifests (the one marked 1) is the `MyApp.manifest` (which is maybe why it works ok in windows 7?) and sure enough if I delete the second manifest the app works perfectly. Strangely if I change the number in the RC file the number 1 changes with it but the second manifest remains at number 2.

I think the second manifest may have something to do with runtime themes but disabling that simply doesn't work (I untick the checkbox, close project options, open project options and the checkbox is ticked).

so what is causing the second manifest to appear? and how do I get rid of it?

Delphi Version is 2007

Comment: MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID of 2 is normally used in a DLL. I doubt that helps you but it won't be produced by the Delphi IDE. Just search your project for $R and you should find it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came back to this project after working on something else for a while and deleted the existing .res file **before opening the project**

I think Delphi caches the projects .res file in memory and only updates it when compiling/building since this problem has entirely disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna use your own manifest , you must disable the manifest generated by delphi following these steps depending of you delphi version.

1. Remove any [`TXPManifest`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/XPMan.TXPManifest) component from your project
2. Remove any reference to the XpMan unit in your project
3. Disable the option "Enable runtime themes", present in the project -> options -> application

Comment: I can't disable the option "Enable runtime themes". It refuses to be unticked (I have no idea why)

Comment: when you say `...I untick the checkbox, close project options, open project options and the checkbox is ticked` this can be caused maybe by some third party plugin in your ide which is enabling this option.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Delphi? Check the uses clause in all of your project files for `UxTheme`; it's the old theme manager from Mike Lischke at SoftGems that was incorporated into the VCL. You can also look for `XPMan`, which adds a manifest to Delphi 7; it's also from Mike. Prior to the inclusion in the VCL, he had it as free OS on his web site.

You'll also need to do a Project->Build rather than just a compile afterwards (or after changing the 'runtime themes' setting as well), in order to force all units to be recompiled and the executable to be fully recreated.

Comment: Added Delphi Version to Question. The app only contains 1 form and the form only contains 1 progress bar. Neither uxTheme nor XPTheme are included anywhere in the app (That I can see)

Comment: Just created a new VCL forms application in D2007 and dropped a button on it. Ran the app, and the button was themed. Used Project->Options->Compiler, unchecked runtime themes, saved changes, and ran the app. The button was drawn unthemed. Repeating this with the same app (toggling option, run, toggle option, run) continues to change the appearance of the button each time.